# NSInvalidArgumentException, Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, parse-platform, firebase-realtime-database

**Situation**

I am trying to change an *Objective-C* project from Parse to firebase. What I am trying to do is replacing Parse codes with corresponding firebase code. This strategy worked for my login page and login was successful
 The login page calls a segue to MainViewController. The MainViewController loads but the app crashes with an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXYOs.png)

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'

**What I Did**

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCk5M.png) is the firebase code I added in LoginViewController `- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender`

```
 //Checking for username and password

_emailId=_emailTextField.text;
_password=_passwordTextField.text;

//reference for firebase
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

if([self isInternet])
{
    //firebase authentication
    [[FIRAuth auth]signInWithEmail:_emailId password:_password completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                          // ...
    if (error) {
            //login failed
            [self failsLoginWithError:@"Please try again later"];
        }
  else
  {
      NSLog(@"Login Successful");
       [self successLoginWithResposne:user];
  }
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SoRh.png) is the parse code I commented out

```
    PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"normal"];
    [query whereKey:@"usermail" equalTo:_emailId];
    [query whereKey:@"password" equalTo:_password];
    [query whereKey:@"user_removed" equalTo:@(0)];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
//login failed
            [self failsLoginWithError:@"Please try again later"];
        }
        if ([objects count]==0) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid username or passowrd");
            [self failsLoginWithError:@"Invalid email or password"];

        } else {

            PFObject *obj = [objects firstObject];
            ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            BOOL isBlocked = [[obj valueForKey:@"blocked"] boolValue];
            BOOL isLogged = [[obj valueForKey:@"logged"]boolValue];
            NSString *userID = [ud objectForKey:@"ObjectID"];

            if (isLogged) {
                if ([userID isEqualToString:obj.objectId]) {

                    if (isBlocked) {
                        [self failsLoginWithError:@"Login Blocked! Please contact your Doctor"];
                    }else{
                        //                        Login success
                        [self successLoginWithResposne:obj];
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //                        login Failed
                    [obj setValue:@(1) forKey:@"blocked"];
                    [obj saveInBackground];
                    [self failsLoginWithError:@"Login Blocked! Please contact your Doctor"];
                }

            }
            else {
                //                    login success
                [obj setValue:@(1) forKey:@"logged"];
                [obj saveInBackground];
                [self successLoginWithResposne:obj];

            }



        }
    } ];
```

The error message says "exception due to comparison with a null value".
Guess this is due to some parse code somewhere comparing a value that is received from the LoginViewController (which I commented out).

**Question**

How to fix this?
How do I find the part where the comparison is happening? 
Do I have to replace every parse code with firebase code before executing?
if so, How to find every parse code in the project?

Crash report:

[image: 4]

Exact line where code crashes:

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

You may look for the User system parse has build in

Example

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_emailId password:_password
  block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (user) {
      if(user[@"blocked"] == @YES){
           return [PFUser logOut];
      }else{
          // USER AUTHENTICATED
      }

    } else {
      // Password, Conection
    }
}];
```

All local store will be available by using this anywhare in your app:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
} else {
    // show the signup or login screen
}
```

If you want to auth with the email insted of a "username" just use the username as the email in registration.

Comment: Fixed it. It was not because of parse. The `NSUserDefaults` was not working properly. Thanks for your Time.